# GMT and UTC formatter with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

i wrote function that converting current time utc-gmt or gmt -utc. The functions just works fine if msgArrivedDate is null. If it's not ( that means , msgArrivedDate comes from rest service  that doses not convert .

jSON parse part :

```
NSArray *messageSentTime = [[args valueForKey:@"messageSendDate"] objectAtIndex:0];

    for(int i=0 ;i< [messageSentTime count]; i++)
    {
        //[self timeZoneFormatter:@"GMT" :[messageSentTime objectAtIndex:i]];

        NSLog(@"Converted time = %@",[self timeZoneFormatter:@"GMT" :[messageSentTime objectAtIndex:i]]);
```

Function part :

```
-(id)timeZoneFormatter:(NSString *)formatType : (NSString *)msgArrivedDate
{
    NSDate *date;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];


    if([msgArrivedDate length] > 0)
    {

        date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:msgArrivedDate];

    } else {

        date = [NSDate date];
    }


    if([formatType isEqualToString:@"UTC"])
    {
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

    }

    if([formatType isEqualToString:@"GMT"])
    {
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    }

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    return dateString;
}
```

ReST  returned me to these values in UTC format :

> ```
> "2013-09-24 15:03:17",
> "2013-09-25 12:09:22",
> "2013-09-25 13:07:45",
> "2013-09-25 13:08:19",
> "2013-09-25 14:22:38"
> ```

When i call the function, `(NSLog(@"Converted time = %@",[self timeZoneFormatter:@"GMT" :[messageSentTime objectAtIndex:i]]))` returns :

```
 messageSentTime = (
    "2013-09-24 15:03:17",
    "2013-09-25 12:09:22",
    "2013-09-25 13:07:45",
    "2013-09-25 13:08:19",
    "2013-09-25 14:22:38" )
```

I think i am just missing little issue over here :( couldn't find yet ...

Comment: UTC and GMT are the same time.

Comment: UTC and GMT is just the parameter that i used in  function, GMT mean that in my scope = NSTimeZone localTimeZone, UTC = NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"] which are works fine with null parameter on my function

Comment: Don't use GMT to mean something it ain't.  Use LCL or some such to mean local time.

Comment: there are TONS of date formatter questions here + the docs are quite detailed + It is pointless to convert UTC<>GMT

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

to this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

**Edit:** This method will handle translating the date string from UTC to GMT and from GMT to UTC:

```
- (id)translateDate:(NSString *)msgArrivedDate
               from:(NSString *)fromTimeZone
                 to:(NSString *)toTimeZone {
    NSDate *date = nil;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    if([fromTimeZone isEqualToString:@"UTC"]) {
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    }

    if([fromTimeZone isEqualToString:@"GMT"]) {
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    }

    if([msgArrivedDate length] > 0) {
        date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:msgArrivedDate];
    } else {
        date = [NSDate date];
    }

    if([toTimeZone isEqualToString:@"UTC"]) {
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    }

    if([toTimeZone isEqualToString:@"GMT"]) {
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    }

    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return dateString;
}
```

Converting "2013-09-25 14:22:38" from UTC to GMT (i.e. local time, in your usage of GMT) will result in `2013-09-25 15:22:38`, and similarly, converting "2013-09-25 14:22:38" from GMT to UTC will result in `2013-09-25 13:22:38`.

Comment: Another problem just appeared . Same issue just happened for GMT to UTC conversion. If i set nil the function gets true time format for UTC with setting date = [NSDate date]; But if msgArrivedDate has a value , function does not convert GMT to UTC ...

Comment: you don't go from GMT to UTC or vice versa

Comment: Why don't i  ? I need to convert to UTC to post service , in order to fetch new messages ...