# How to add raw body in AFHTTPSessionManager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I want to request raw body in JSON like [Postman body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghztm.png). Please answer this.

Comment: Does the array contain the 'time' in text strings or actual NSDate objects?

Comment: Time is in string text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37180693/date-predicate-does-not-work see my question use filterMeetingsBasedOnTime method for your goal

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSMutableArray *)filterMeetingsBasedOnTime:(BOOL)isPastMtng :(NSMutableArray*)arr
{
NSDate *dt = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *df =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];


NSMutableArray *arrMeeting = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary *sMtngDict in arr)
{
    NSDate  *meetDate = [df dateFromString:[sMtngDict valueForKey:@"time"]];

if(isPastMtng)
{
    if([meetDate timeIntervalSinceDate:dt]<0)
    {
        [arrMeeting addObject:sMtngDict];
    }
}

}

return arrMeeting;
}
```

It will help

Comment: it's take current time in UTC
How to get it in gmt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024092/gmt-and-utc-formatter-with-nsdateformatter @RajUpadhyay

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray *pastTimeArray=[NSMutableArray array];

```
for ( NSDictionary *dict in TimesArray)//TimesArray is your input array
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

    NSDate *givenTime=[formatter dateFromString:[dict objectForKey:@"time"]];
    NSString *temptime = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSDate *CurrentTime=[formatter dateFromString:temptime];
    NSComparisonResult result=[CurrentTime compare:givenTime];

    if (result==NSOrderedAscending)
    {
        [pastTimeArray addObject:[formatter stringFromDate:givenTime]];
        NSLog(@"%@",pastTimeArray);
    }
}
```